# Why Attributes Toolbar is not coming back?

Tags: qgis, gui, toolbar

For some reason I lost my attributes toolbar in QGIS (on 3.10, 3.16 and 3.20, all lost). I've tried to untick/tick the attributes toolbar, have closed/opened QGIS, and restarted my PC, but it's just not coming back.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I need the info button, ruler, etc.

Comment: Settings>user profiles>new profile can reset settings https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_configuration.html#user-profiles